# Converting a pre-image resistant hash to second pre-image resistant

Tags: hash, 2nd-preimage-resistance

I am looking for some standard conversion from any hash function $f$, which has pre-image resistance, to another hash function with second preimage resistance. Is there such a standard conversion?

Comment: Can collision resistance be assumed too? Or only pre-image resistance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. ​ I believe [this](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/UOWHFs-eprint-mar10.pdf) is the standard conversion.

(That link is to the paper "Universal One-Way Hash Functions via Inaccessible Entropy".)

Comment: May you please describe what the link contains in case it goes down?

Comment: The only better description I can think of would be a summary of the abstract. $\;$