# Example: pre-image resistance to second pre-image resistance

Tags: preimage-resistance

It is possible to convert a pre-image resistant function $f:\{0,1\}^{n}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n}$ to a second-preimage resistant function? I am thinking to use a pseudo-random generator and construct that second pre-image resistant function in this way:

$$F(x)=f(x)+\text{PRNG}(x).$$

What kind of tests I need to make to verify this function is second-preimage resistant?

Comment: Just let me quickly recap this: $f$ is pre-image resistant and $F$ should be pre-image resistant *and* second pre-image resistant?

Comment: @SEJPM Yes it is

Comment: Related: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27071/converting-a-pre-image-resistance-to-second-pre-image-resistance

Comment: The constructions of that paper are not for preimage-resistance.

Comment: You would need to make the same tests as for any arbitrary construction: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/183/991

Comment: @juaninf Is the restriction of the input of $f$ to $\{0,1\}^n$ (instead of $\{0,1\}^*$) for a particular reason?

Comment: @mikeazo The length preservation indeed makes things a bit trivial. to "convert" just ignore the function and use the identity function instead (or any other permutation for that matter). Since there is only one preimage for each image, there can be no second preimage attack.

Comment: @Maeher but with the identity function, you don't have preimage resistance.

Comment: @Maeher: to add to mikeazo's comment, if $f$ is pre-image resistant and injective then it is trivially second pre-image resistant. But it could be the case that the image of $f$ is only a subset of $\{0,1\}^n$.